# Calculate a Lagged column on itself

Tags: r

I'm certain there is an easier way to accomplish this.  I have the following dataframe:

```
B <- c(1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0)

A <- c(1:10)

df <- as.data.frame(cbind(A,B))
```

What I would like to do is add a third column (C) that applies column B, unless column B is 0, in which case apply the percent change in column A to the previous result of column C.

Here is what I did:

```
library(Hmisc)

df$New <- ifelse(df$B!=0, df$B, df$A/Lag(df$A, shift=1)*Lag(df$B, shift=1))

df$New2 <- ifelse(df$New !=0, df$New, df$A/Lag(df$A, shift=1)*Lag(df$New, shift=1))

df$New3 <- ifelse(df$New2 !=0, df$New2, df$A/Lag(df$A, shift=1)*Lag(df$New2, shift=1)) 

df$C <- pmax(df$New, df$New2, df$New3)  

df<- df[c(1,2,6)]
```

Essentially, I need to calculate on the column based on the previous calculated result, so maybe sapply, but not sure.

Comment: Don't do any version of `data.frame(cbind(...))`; you're making a matrix before making a data.frame, which will cause type errors later when all of your data isn't numeric. Just use `data.frame` by itself.

Comment: chuck it in a `for` loop... `df$Cnew = df$B ; for(i in which(df$B==0)) df$Cnew[i] = df$Cnew[i-1]* df$A[i]/df$A[i-1]`

Comment: Excellent!  Thank you. user20650.  Great tip alistaire, I hadn't realized the data.frame(cbind...)) issue.